# Google Ajax Library API & jQuery(function() {})

Tags: jquery, google-ajax-api

i wonder if i use

```
google.load("jquery", 1);
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    // i still need to check if document has finished loading with 
    $(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
});
```

the question is when google.setOnLoadCallback() is called it does not mean the document has finished loading right? or can i do stuff like ... below ... straight away?

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
    $("#elem").doSomething();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Google AJAX API docs](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/#GettingStarted):

> **google.setOnLoadCallback** is used as a helper for *window.onload*, which only happens once, when the document is loading. Therefore, for dynamic loading of the API (such as after user interaction), google.load with the callback option should be used instead (see below).

`window.load` will always fire after [`DOMContentLoaded`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L409) that is the equivalent of `jQuery(document).ready` for most cases. When not available, jQuery will fallback to [`onreadystatechange`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L418) or [`onload`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L421) (IE), or [`load`](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L412) (standard).

Since worst case if both jQuery and google falling back to the `load` event, you can safely use the second method.